# Php pdo sum of column (number datatype)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I need to get `sum` of values from table `track_aktivnosti` from column `vrednost`, so I write:

```
 $rs = $db->prepare('SELECT sum(vrednost) FROM track_aktivnosti WHERE user_id=:user_id AND tabela=:radnici AND id_tabele=:id_tabele');
          $rs->bindParam(':user_id', $user_id); 
          $rs->bindParam(':id_tabele', $r['ID']); 
          $rs->bindParam(':radnici', $radnici); 
          $rs->execute();
          $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $rs);
```

but as a result I get just `1` which is not corrent sum of values from column `vrednost`. What can be a problem here?

Comment: Shouldn't `$r['ID']);` be `$rs['ID']);` ?

Comment: no becouse my full code is: foreach($result as $r) {
          $temp = array();
          // the following line will be used to slice the Pie chart
          $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $r['ID']); 
    $temp[] = array('v' => (string) $r['ime_prezime']);
   
    $rs = $db->prepare('SELECT sum(vrednost) FROM track_aktivnosti WHERE user_id=:user_id AND tabela=:radnici AND id_tabele=:id_tabele');
          $rs->bindParam(':user_id', $user_id); 
    $rs->bindParam(':id_tabele', $r['ID']); 
    $rs->bindParam(':radnici', $radnici); 
       $rs->execute();
    $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $rs);

Comment: My mistake. Make sure that your column is in fact called `ID` and not `id` On some systems, that could be a factor. Just stating what could be a (*probable*) contributing factor.

Comment: @gmaestro: Shankar's answer is correct and does what you need. But just curious: does `$temp[] = array('v' => (int) $rs->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM));` work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rewrite

```
   $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $rs);
```

to

```
   $sumRows = $rs->fetchColumn();
```

You could `echo $sumRows;` to print the sum returned by your query.